# How to loop images in array with prev/next functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have a JS array `imgs[]`.

The array holds image paths like this: `["img/image1.png", "img/image2.png"]`

I have two functions:

```
function prev() {
    $('#project-image').html("<img src='"+imgs[0]+"' alt='Projekt'/>")
}

function next() {
    $('#project-image').html("<img src='"+imgs[1]+"' alt='Projekt'/>")
}
```

They are called within the HTML like this:

```
<nav id="pagination">
  <a id="prev" href="javascript:prev();"></a>
  <a id="next" href="javascript:next();"></a>
</nav>
```

However, the problem I have is that right now they are set to fixed keys within the array (hardcoded by me), like `imgs[1]`.

How could I dynamically loop through all images in the array with those two functions?

When clicking the "next" link I want to load the next image in the array. When clicking the "prev" link I want to load the previous image. My array consists mostly of more than two images and moreover they are not all named like the example above. So the names of the images vary.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/azebog/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
var images = [
  "img/image1.jpg",
  "img/image2.jpg",
  "img/image3.jpg"
];

// ======================================

var tot = images.length;
var c = 0; // current image (array key index)

function loadImage(){
  $("<img/>").attr("src",images[c]).load(function() {
      $('#gallery').html( this );
  }); 
}
loadImage(); // load 1 image

$('#prev, #next').click(function(){
  id= this.id==='next' ? c++ : c-- ;
  c= c==-1 ? tot-1 : c%tot ;
  loadImage(); 
});
```

While the code is pretty self explanatory
`id= this.id==='next' ? c++ : c-- ;` will determine the **`ID`** of the clicked button
and do increase or decrease the `c` value which is needed to get the exact array key.

To loop the array keys use this *ternary operator* "trick": `c= c==-1 ? tot-1 : c%tot ;` where `c` is the current key index and `tot` is the total number of array keys.

This should give you a good start. To entertain your visitors with a "Loading image..." info, I'll leave it to you! :) Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote [a handy object](http://jsfiddle.net/xa2kw/1/) for it.

### Cursor object

```
$.cursor = function(options)​ {
  var cursor = this;
  var array = options.array;
  var idx = options.position || 0;
  cursor.prev = function() {
    if(idx > 0) {
      return array[--idx];
    }
    return null;
  };
  cursor.current = function() {
    if(idx < array.length) {
      return array[idx];
    }
    return null;
  };
  cursor.next = function() {
    if(idx + 1 < array.length) {
      return array[++idx];
    }
    return null;
  };
  return cursor;
};
```

### Example

```
var cursor = $.cursor({ array: [1,2,3,4,5] });

$("#prev").click(function(){
  if(cursor.prev() !== null) {
    $("#cur").html(cursor.current());
  }
});

$("#next").click(function(){
  if(cursor.next() !== null) {
    $("#cur").html(cursor.current());
  }
});

$("#cur").html(cursor.current());
```

​

Answer (score 0):

first find in which offset of array is the image link located, then for *next()* go to the next offset, if you reached the last offset show 0 (zero) offset and so on. For *prev()* go to the current image offset and offset - 1 will give you the previous image, if you reach the offset 0 (zero) go the last offset.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just store the current image key in a var.

```
current_image = 0;

function prev() {
    current_image--;
    $('#project-image').html("<img src='"+imgs[current_image]+"' alt='Projekt'/>")
}

function next() {
    current_image++;
    $('#project-image').html("<img src='"+imgs[current_image]+"' alt='Projekt'/>")
}
```

Comment: the problem with that is that it counts also beneath 0 and above the highest array value. there is no `imgs[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're forgetting to create a var index; outside your functions and using it dynamically. Then, instead of 'hard coding' the values, you can use index++ or index-- to change the offset by one. Later you can even use if's to check for the current index, and improve your code to do what you want when showing, for example, the last img of the array. Hope it helps!